# UIButton is changing other UIButton's in collectionView cell, how do I prevent this?

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, custom-cell

I've created a custom collectionView cell class that contains a UIButton. So each cell contains it's own button that a user can press. However whenever one cell button is tapped it causes background color changes to buttons in other cells. I want it to where only the selected button's background color is changed instead and to prevent the change to other buttons. Below is my code:

```
      override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! SubjectsCell


    cell.subjectButton.setTitle(subjectNames[indexPath.row], for: .normal)
    cell.subjectButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updateBackgroundColor(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    if cell.subjectButton.isChosen == selectedState{
        cell.subjectButton.backgroundColor = .green        }

    else if cell.subjectButton.isChosen != selectedState {
        cell.subjectButton.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 34.0/255.0, green: 210.0/255.0, blue: 255.0/255.0, alpha: 1)


    }

    return cell
```

I realize that dequeueReusableCell causes some cells to be reused, if this is my problem how I prevent cell changes happening to random cell's and only affect the cell that the tapped button is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that `dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:for:)` is the source of the issue here! You just need to have your cell class override `UICollectionReusableView`'s `prepareForReuse()` method and reset the background to whatever it needs to be.

You may need to change your data model so you have a way of remembering which cells have had the button pressed since the cells can't hold on to that data without causing problems.

Also note that calling `addTarget` inside that `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` may cause problems later, targets are typically only added once when the object is set up initially. To avoid issues you should set that up either in the nib / storyboard as an action, or when you setup the view objects if you're doing programmatic view setup.

[Here's Apple's documentation on prepareForReuse().](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionreusableview/1620141-prepareforreuse)

Comment: Thanks for your enlightenment! Overriding the prepareForReuse worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class SubjectsCell : UICollectionViewCell 
{
@IBAction func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton) {
 updateBackgroundColor()
}
}
```

so the cell view background update should present in SubjectsCell because its a view update not in job of viewController.